# Lewy's example: solution with nowhere Hölder derivatives

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Hans Lewy shows in his 1957 example that a certain linear PDE with polynomial coefficients cannot have a solution with Hölder derivatives in any open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I find this example cited everywhere as a "linear equation without solution"; however that is not what appears to be shown in the paper, since (if I recall correctly) there are $C^1$ functions that are nowhere Hölder.

Is a (hypothetical) "solution" with non-Hölder derivatives simply not considered "well-behaved" enough to be called a solution? Are there other results related to that paper that go further?

What is the point I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the introduction of Hölder's condition in the second part of Lewy's paper is a bit unsatisfactory. Hartman removed it 1-2 years later (depending on if you look at the publication or submission dates). [His paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1959-010-02/S0002-9939-1959-0125304-8/home.html) is in open access (three cheers to the AMS).